# How do I spawn a urdf object programmatically?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-pcl, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I take a .pcd file as input and process the pointcloud using pcl. I then want to spawn an object in Gazebo using the results of that processing so that I can simulate the manipulation of that object with a pr2. Is there a programmatic way to do this , i.e. using c++.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12017/how-do-i-spawn-a-urdf-object-programmatically?/) by [Raskolnikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1416/raskolnikov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-11-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you spawn it in a launch file it works like this:

```
 <node name="spawned_object_name" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" 
 args="-urdf -file $(find rospackagename)/path/to/file.urdf -model 
 object_name_from_gazebo_perspective  -x 0.50 -y 0.05 -z 0.65" 
 respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

If you look at

http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API

it tells you that there is also a ROS service gazebo/spawn_model which you can call programmatically through a ROS message - this seems like the right way to do it.

Here is the documentation of the service:

http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gazebo/html/srv/SpawnModel.html

---

Originally posted by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) with karma: 535 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4